# Calculate $\int^{\pi/6}_{-\pi/6}\frac{\sin^3x(1+\cos^2x)}{4+\cos x+\sin^2x} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I calculate $$\int^{\pi/6}_{-\pi/6}\frac{\sin^3x(1+\cos^2x)}{4+\cos x+\sin^2x} \mathrm dx?$$

I can't find any substitution, or a way to integrate it by parts. I also tried finding an identity that may help me work this out but all I could get to was:

$$\frac{\sin^3x(1+\cos^2x)}{4+\cos x+\sin^2x} = \frac{\sin x(1-\cos^4x)}{-\cos^2x+\cos x+5}$$ Which also doesn't seem very helpful.

How can I approach this?

Comment: It's an odd function on a symmetric interval. Ball in your court.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$, and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$.

So you can easily check that

$$\frac{\sin^3(-x)(1+\cos^2(-x))}{4+\cos(-x)+\sin^2(-x)}=-\frac{\sin^3(x)(1+\cos^2(x))}{4+\cos(x)+\sin^2(x)}$$

so

$$\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\frac{\sin^3(x)(1+\cos^2(x))}{4+\cos(x)+\sin^2(x)}\mathrm{d} x=\int_{-\pi/6}^0+\int_{0}^{\pi/6}=-\int_{0}^{\pi/6}+\int_{0}^{\pi/6}=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If

$$f(x):=\frac{\sin ^3(x) \left(\cos ^2(x)+1\right)}{\sin ^2(x)+\cos (x)+4},$$

what is

$$f(-x)?$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

You can continue your solution.

Put $\cos x = t$

$- \sin x dx = dt$

Answer (score 0):

Hint the denominator is an even function ie $f (x)=f (-x) $ while numerator has $\sin^3 (x) $ which is an odd function as $sin (-x)=sin (x) $ thus function is symmetric about y axis thus the value of integral is $0$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use $\displaystyle I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx,$

$\displaystyle I+I=\int_a^b\{f(x)+f(a+b-x)\}\ dx$

Here $b=-a$